# Custom list defintion with OrderedList property

Tags: list-definition, ordering

I've created a custom list in SharePoint 2010 from a **custom content type** (inherit from item) and I would like to give the users the option to order the items in this list - similar to how users can order items in an out of the box Links list.

In SharePoint 2007 I did this several times by using the **OrderedList** property in the List element of the **schema.xml**, and I've tried the same approach in 2010. I also added the OrderedView property on the View element.

After creating a list from this defintion, when I look at the list settings and attempt to modify a view then I see the options that indicate that the list can be ordered by a user. However, I'm **missing the button** (Change Item Order) on the ribbon that allows a user to order the list.

I *can* navigate to the /_layouts/reorder.aspx?List=... and order the list from that page - so my assumption is that there is some logic built into the ribbon which is stopping it from displaying the button. I've exhausted areas to look into so any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Why was this closed for being "too localized"? I have this exact issue.